# Find Row Number of Record in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have a table with one column - called 'person' that contains a list of names. I want to find a specific person based off his *index*.

I tried using a sql variable to track each column index but the issue is - is that if I have a table of 5 records this will always output the 5th record.

```
SET @row_num = 0; SELECT @row_num := @row_num + 1 as row1 ,person FROM table; 
SELECT row1 from table WHERE person = 'name'
```

Comment: In the absence of an `ORDER BY` clause, the ordering of rows in a result set is *unpredictable.* That is, the RDMS server is free to return the rows in any order that suits its purposes. Notice that servers sometimes change ordering when the table crosses a size threshold. So, what you're doing here is building in a latent bug. Put the index value in a column!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend changing your database to add a second column for row_id. This is a fairly common practice. Then you can just use

```
SELECT * from table WHERE row_id = 3;
```

This will return the third row.

Comment: `row_id == 3` is it correct? shouldn't it be `row_id = 3`?

Comment: Could be I don't remember exact syntax. But the intent is clear.

Comment: I thought MySQL had a implicit index functionality but maybe I'm wrong. I dont know if this is the best way to do it

Comment: Fixed it for =3. And @BDillan, this is probably the best way. It is very lightweight and common practice to include some kind of index column or row_id as multiple people have suggested now.

Answer (score 0):

Another best possible way would be by means of a `TEMPORARY TABLE` as explained below

create a temp table

```
create temporary table temptab(ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,Person VARCHAR(30))
```

Then insert data to temp table as

```
insert into temptab(Person) select Person from mytable
```

Then select the specific index person name from temp table like

```
select Person from temptab where ID = 5
```

Comment: I would need two queries. One to do this and another to drop the table :/

Comment: @BDillan, that's outside of your post but anyways to drop a table just say `drop table table_name`. If you have a specific question then I would suggest to post it separately.

Comment: @BDillan, Instead of a temporary table, you can as well use a normal table and then drop the old existing table. Also, consider accepting the answer if it helped.